# Latex PGFPLOTS: Set value between ticks

Tags: pgfplots, dateplot

I am trying to plot the outside temperature of a city of an average year. Therefore, I want the values (month of year) to be in between the xtick lines, and not on the line. Can somebody help me with this?

Here is my Latex Code and I have added two pictures, how it currently looks like and how I want it to look like.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{tikz} % To generate the plot from csv
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\pgfplotsset{compat=newest, every axis/.append style={line width=1.5pt}}
\usepgfplotslibrary{units} % Allows to enter the units nicely
\usepgfplotslibrary{dateplot}

\sisetup{round-mode = places, round-precision = 2,}

\begin{figure}[h!]
      \begin{center}
        \begin{tikzpicture}
          \begin{axis}[
              date coordinates in=x,date ZERO=2017-01-01,xticklabel=\month,
              xmin=2017-01-01,xmax=2018-01-01,
              xtick = {2017-01-01, 2017-02-01, 2017-03-01, 2017-04-01, 2017-05-01, 2017-06-01, 2017-07-01, 2017-08-01, 2017-09-01, 2017-10-01, 2017-11-01, 2017-12-01},
              width= \linewidth, height = 8cm, 
              grid=major,% Display a grid
              grid style={dashed,gray!30},
              xlabel= Month of year, 
              ylabel= Temperature,
              y unit=\si{^\circ C},
              legend style={at={(1,1)},anchor=north east},
              no markers,
            ]
            \addplot table[x=Day,y=T_min, col sep=comma] {tables/Temperatures.csv}; 
            \addlegendentry{\emph{$T_{min}$}} 
          \end{axis}
        \end{tikzpicture}
        \caption{Average Outside Temperature between 2007 - 2017}
      \end{center}
    \end{figure}
\end {document}
```

This is how it is currently looking:

[image]

And I want it to look like this:

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Answer (score 4):

A simple `xshift` might also do. I also made some minor additional changes, and tried to solve the problem in general. The problem is that, as far as I could see, the (average) distance between the ticks is not known at the time when one would need it. In principle, the answer would be simple in this case if you humans would not have different numbers of days per month. That's the reason why the labels are not perfectly centered, and why this is most visible in February. I also added some routine that retrieves the distance between the last two ticks, but in the present case it only tells you that December (or January) has 31 days, which you may have known before. And, as I mentioned, the information comes too late anyway. Nonetheless, I decided to leave it here because it might be useful for another problem.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{tikz} % To generate the plot from csv
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\GetXDistance}[1]{\edef#1{\pgfplots@tick@distance@x}}
\makeatother
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest, every axis/.append style={line width=1.5pt}}
\usepgfplotslibrary{units} % Allows to enter the units nicely
\usepgfplotslibrary{dateplot}

\sisetup{round-mode = places, round-precision = 2,}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[h!]
\makeatletter
      \begin{center}
        \begin{tikzpicture}
          \begin{axis}[
              date coordinates in=x,date ZERO=2017-01-01,xticklabel=\month,
              xmin=2017-01-01,xmax=2018-01-01,
              xtick = {2017-01-01, 2017-02-01, 2017-03-01, 2017-04-01, 2017-05-01, 2017-06-01, 2017-07-01, 2017-08-01, 2017-09-01, 2017-10-01, 2017-11-01, 2017-12-01},
              width=\linewidth, height = 8cm,
              grid=major,% Display a grid
              grid style={dashed,gray!30},
              xticklabel style={xshift=15,anchor=north},
              xlabel= Month of year, 
              ylabel= Temperature,
              y unit=\si{\celsius}, % ^\circ and \si ?
              legend style={at={(1,1)},anchor=north east},
              no markers, 
            ]
            \addplot coordinates {(2017-01-01,1) (2017-02-01,2) 
            (2017-03-01,2) (2017-04-01,3) (2017-05-01,3)
            (2017-06-01,4) (2017-07-01,4) (2017-08-01,4)
            (2017-09-01,3) (2017-10-01,3) (2017-11-01,2)
            (2017-12-01,1) (2018-01-01,1)} \pgfextra{\GetXDistance{\mydist}
            \typeout{\mydist}} 
            ;
%            \addplot table[x=Day,y=T_min, col sep=comma] {tables/Temperatures.csv}; 
            \addlegendentry{$T_{min}$} % \emph didn't have any effect here
          \end{axis}
        \end{tikzpicture}
        \caption{Average Outside Temperature between 2007 - 2017}
      \end{center}
      \makeatother
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**UPDATE**: Just for fun, using the fact that the labels are nodes, one can center the xtick labels.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{tikz} % To generate the plot from csv
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\newcounter{tickindex}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\GetXDistance}[1]{\edef#1{\pgfplots@tick@distance@x}}
\makeatother
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest, every axis/.append style={line width=1.5pt}}
\usepgfplotslibrary{units} % Allows to enter the units nicely
\usepgfplotslibrary{dateplot}

\sisetup{round-mode = places, round-precision = 2,}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[h!]
\makeatletter
      \begin{center}
        \begin{tikzpicture}
          \begin{axis}[
              date coordinates in=x,date ZERO=2017-01-01,xticklabel=\month,
              xmin=2017-01-01,xmax=2018-01-01,
              xtick = {2017-01-01, 2017-02-01, 2017-03-01, 2017-04-01, 2017-05-01, 2017-06-01, 2017-07-01, 2017-08-01, 2017-09-01, 2017-10-01, 2017-11-01, 2017-12-01,2018-01-01},
              width=\linewidth, height = 8cm,
              grid=major,% Display a grid
              grid style={dashed,gray!30},
              xticklabel style={opacity=0,anchor=north east,name=x-\tick},
              xlabel= Month of year, 
              ylabel= Temperature,
              y unit=\si{\celsius}, % ^\circ and \si ?
              legend style={at={(1,1)},anchor=north east},
              no markers, 
            ]
            \addplot coordinates {(2017-01-01,1) (2017-02-01,2) 
            (2017-03-01,2) (2017-04-01,3) (2017-05-01,3)
            (2017-06-01,4) (2017-07-01,4) (2017-08-01,4)
            (2017-09-01,3) (2017-10-01,3) (2017-11-01,2)
            (2017-12-01,1) (2018-01-01,1)};
%            \addplot table[x=Day,y=T_min, col sep=comma] {tables/Temperatures.csv}; 
            \addlegendentry{$T_{min}$} % \emph didn't have any effect here
          \end{axis}
          \foreach \X [count=\Y] in {2017-01-01,2017-02-01,2017-03-01,2017-04-01,2017-05-01,2017-06-01,2017-07-01,2017-08-01,2017-09-01,2017-10-01,2017-11-01,2017-12-01,2018-01-01}
          {\ifnum\Y=1
          \else
          \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\Month}{\Y-1}
          \path (x-\LastTick)--(x-\X.east) node[midway]{\Month};
          \fi
          \xdef\LastTick{\X}
          }
        \end{tikzpicture}
        \caption{Average Outside Temperature between 2007 - 2017}
      \end{center}
      \makeatother
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, your second idea of interpreting the labels as nodes works perfectly!

Comment: @JvR Glad to hear! If the solution worked for you please see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1852/how-do-you-accept-an-answer) and perhaps [How does accepting an answer work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).

Answer (score 3):

I can't reproduce your plot because I don't have the .csv file, but one idea is to make two overlapping axes. You can set one axis to be a `ybar interval`, which will put your x axis labels in the intervals between tick marks. On the other axis, you plot your data but hide ticks and labels.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{tikz} % To generate the plot from csv
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15, every axis/.append style={line width=1.5pt},width= \linewidth, height = 8cm}
\usepgfplotslibrary{units} % Allows to enter the units nicely
\usepgfplotslibrary{dateplot}

\sisetup{round-mode = places, round-precision = 2,}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[h!]
      \begin{center}
        \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[ybar interval,
              date coordinates in=x,
              date ZERO=2017-01-01,
              xticklabel=\month,
              xmin=2017-01-01,
              xmax=2018-01-01,
              xtick = {2017-01-01, 2017-02-01, 2017-03-01, 2017-04-01, 2017-05-01, 2017-06-01, 2017-07-01, 2017-08-01, 2017-09-01, 2017-10-01, 2017-11-01, 2017-12-01},
              xlabel= Month of year, 
              ylabel= Temperature,
              y unit=\si{^\circ C},
              grid=major,% Display a grid
              grid style={dashed,gray!30},
        ] 
        \end{axis}
          \begin{axis}[
              xticklabel=\empty,
              legend style={at={(1,1)},anchor=north east},
              no markers,
              axis lines=none,
            ]
%            \addplot table[x=Day,y=T_min, col sep=comma] {tables/Temperatures.csv}; 
            \addlegendentry{\emph{$T_{min}$}} 
          \end{axis}
        \end{tikzpicture}
        \caption{Average Outside Temperature between 2007 - 2017}
      \end{center}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Did you try your code with some nontrivial plot? When I added `\addplot coordinates {(2017-01-01,1) (2017-02-01,2) 
            (2017-03-01,2) (2017-04-01,3) (2017-05-01,3)
            (2017-06-01,4) (2017-07-01,4) (2017-08-01,4)
            (2017-09-01,3) (2017-10-01,3) (2017-11-01,2)
            (2017-12-01,1) (2018-01-01,1)} ;`, I received some strange errors. Note that I am *not* saying you did something wrong, I am just curious to know what's going on.

Comment: @marmot I did not try with a trivial plot, but I think the errors are because `date coordinates in=x` was not also passed to the second set of axes. I think doing so will make things complicated though, so your solution is probably better. My first thought was actually to use `xshift`, but I wasn't sure how to reliably center the labels (which you solved in your edit.)

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility is to use/add `extra x ticks` at every 15th of the month and show the `xticklabels` there. For details please have a look at the comments in the code.

```
% used PGFPlots v1.16
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{siunitx}
    \sisetup{
        round-mode=places,
        round-precision=2,
    }
\usepackage{pgfplots}
    \usepgfplotslibrary{
        dateplot,
        units,
    }
    \pgfplotsset{
        compat=1.3,
        every axis/.append style={
            line width=1.5pt,
        },
    }
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        width=\linewidth,
        height=8cm,
        date coordinates in=x,
        date ZERO=2017-01-01,
        xlabel=Month of year,
        ylabel=Temperature,
        y unit=\si{\celsius},
        xmin=2017-01-01,
        xmax=2018-01-01,
        xtick={2017-01-01, 2017-02-01, 2017-03-01, 2017-04-01, 2017-05-01, 2017-06-01, 2017-07-01, 2017-08-01, 2017-09-01, 2017-10-01, 2017-11-01, 2017-12-01},
        % don't show the labels here ...
        xticklabels={},
        % ... but at the 15th of every month ...
        extra x ticks={2017-01-15, 2017-02-15, 2017-03-15, 2017-04-15, 2017-05-15, 2017-06-15, 2017-07-15, 2017-08-15, 2017-09-15, 2017-10-15, 2017-11-15, 2017-12-15},
        % ... with the corresponding month number
        extra x tick label=\month,
        grid=major,
        grid style={dashed,gray!30},
        % but don't show the grid or the tick for the `extra ticks'
        extra x tick style={
            grid=none,
            major tick length=0pt,
        },
        no markers,
    ]
%        \addplot table[x=Day,y=T_min, col sep=comma] {tables/Temperatures.csv};
        % (borrowed from marmot's answer)
        \addplot coordinates {
            (2017-01-01,1) (2017-02-01,2) (2017-03-01,2)
            (2017-04-01,3) (2017-05-01,3) (2017-06-01,4)
            (2017-07-01,4) (2017-08-01,4) (2017-09-01,3)
            (2017-10-01,3) (2017-11-01,2) (2017-12-01,1)
            (2018-01-01,1)
        };
        \legend{$T_{\min}$}
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: image showing the result of above code]

Comment: You just copy elements from my answer without mentioning that. Wouldn't you agree mentioning these would be more appropriate?

Comment: @marmot, I have ...

Comment: Really? Like the `\si{\celsius}` and dropping the `\emph` from the legend entry?

Comment: @marmot, my friend. Because we had the "discussion" some time ago, I will never ever copy something from you again without referencing. Can you believe that when I start with the code of OP that I come to the same solution (in some parts) as you do without ever having a look at your code? I guess you agree that everyone who has ever used `siunitx` (seriously) will write `\si{\celsius}`. And perhaps you noticed that I not only removed `\emph` but did two other changes in that line as well.

Comment: @marmot, is that fine for you?

Comment: @marmot, since I have answered your question(s) and asked you if you are fine with that you have written up to now 12 answers and 25 comments. Did you miss to answer or do you simply not want to answer me?